# laravel 5 make my own Error message when mysql error message flash

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

in handler.php

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
     //i changed  
 // return parent::render($request, $e);
   //to
  return redirect()->back()->withErrors($e->errorInfo); 
}
```

in mysql  student email unique

so when i tried to update duplicate email i get error message as 
23000
1062
Duplicate entry 'jon@yahoo.com' for key 'un_studentEmail'

which is go

what I need is that : i want to make change for flashing Error some thing like

The Email  jon@yahoo.com is duplicate please enter other Email

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use [Laravel Validation](http://laravel.com/docs/master/validation) ?

In your controller (or wherever you want to try to insert data in the database) you can pass the request object to a validate method (first parameter is the inputs array, the second the validation rules as a an array and the third optional parameter is an array of custom error messages).

```
// in your controller 
public function store(Request $request) {

    $this->validate($request, [
       'email' => 'unique:YOUR_TABLE'
    ],[
       'email.unique' => 'The email :value is duplicate, please enter another one'.
    ]);

}
```

More information about validation can be found in the docs.

Comment: You can provide an item to ignore; something like:  `'email' => 'unique:YOUR_TABLE,email,id,' . $model->id` - [Further information: see docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-unique)

Comment: when i do 'email' => 'unique:YOUR_TABLE,email,id,' . $model->id,,,, and the  model have UNIQUE KEY `unique_ Email` (`Email`) USING BTREE...
so if  user entered email has been used for other user ???